# How to have two side-by-side columns of key value pairs, with a fixed width between the keys and the values?

Tags: html, css

This is what I have for two side by side columns of key-value pairs with fixed width between the key-values. The columns should get further apart on resize, but not the key value pairs themselves.

I don't really understand how the 'width: 1%' is working. Is there a better solution to this? Is there anything wrong with the way I've done this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/zdt6ejq0/3/

```html
<table width="50%" style="float: left">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 1%"><b>Inment:</b></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">{wbsSubstructure}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>ACDnge&nbsp;Oer:</b></td>
    <td>{changder}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Coct&nbsp;Ne:</b></td>
    <td> {cact}</td>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;"><b>Den:</b></td>
      <td> {dil}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="50%" class="data" style="float: right">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 1%"><b>Inon&nbsp;De:</b></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">{ine}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Sc&nbsp;Nr:</b></td>
    <td> {spmber}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Cct&nbsp;Nr:</b></td>
    <td> {cumber}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;"><b>Don:</b></td>
    <td> {dil}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I give up, what's wrong with the way you're doing this? What are you expecting to see, and what are you seeing? I mean, you're using the deprecated attribute `width` and inline styles and the `b` element for something that could be done with CSS...

Comment: You can achieve the same thing by removing the 1% on the first sell and adding a width of 100% on the second. This will have the second cell occupy the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the tables inside two divs, one floating left, one floating right.

I also recommend to use css classes, not style tags, inside html.

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/69x3rstc/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="floatLeft">
      <table>
         <tr >
            <td><b>Inment:</b></td>
            <td>{wbsSubstructure}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td ><b>ACDnge&nbsp;Oer:</b></td>
            <td>{changder}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td ><b>Coct&nbsp;Ne:</b></td>
            <td> {cact}</td>
         <tr >
            <td><b>Den:</b></td>
            <td> {dil}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="floatRight">
      <table class="data">
         <tr >
            <td><b>Inon&nbsp;De:</b></td>
            <td>{ine}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td ><b>Sc&nbsp;Nr:</b></td>
            <td> {spmber}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td ><b>Cct&nbsp;Nr:</b></td>
            <td> {cumber}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td><b>Don:</b></td>
            <td> {dil}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.floatLeft { width: 50%; float: left; }
.floatRight {width: 50%; float: right; }
.container { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this, each variation depends on your stack, personal preference and or requirements. If you are not locked down to using a table. My preference is to use divs instead to achieve the same effect. This allows you to make use of modern css3 attributes and not be bound by the constraints of a table element. Yes, tables are semantically correct for tabular data, however, the responsive world puts a world of complexities that tables weren't initially designed for.

Ex:

```css
.tabular-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
  
}
.column .column-inner:first-child {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.column .column-inner:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabular-data">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="cell"><strong>Inment:</strong></div>
      <div class="cell"><strong>ACDnge&nbsp;Oer:</strong></div>
      <div class="cell"><strong>Coct&nbsp;Ne:</strong></div>
      <div class="cell"><strong>Den:</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-inner">
        <div class="cell"> {dil}</div>
        <div class="cell"> {cact}</div>
        <div class="cell">{wbsSubstructure}</div>
        <div class="cell">{changder}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="cell"><strong>Inon&nbsp;De:</strong></div>
      <div class="cell"><strong>Sc&nbsp;Nr:</strong></div>
      <div class="cell"><strong>Cct&nbsp;Nr:</strong></div>
      <div class="cell"><strong>Don:</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-inner">
      <div class="cell">{ine}</div>
      <div class="cell">{spmber}</div>
      <div class="cell">{cumber}</div>
      <div class="cell">{dil}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```